# Shared receive buffer for USB endpoints?

Tags: usb, microcontroller

I'm developing a USB device driver for a microcontroller (Atmel/Microchip SAMD21, but I think the question is a general one).  I need multiple endpoints for control & data, and the USB hardware uses per-endpoint descriptors to (among other things) locate buffers for input and output data.

Since IN data is polled at the host's discretion it makes sense that each endpoint has its own IN buffer, so that any endpoint's data (if it has any to send) is immediately available when polled.

But as far as incoming data from SETUP & OUT transactions is concerned, it occurs to me that I can save memory by configuring all endpoints to use a shared buffer.  It seems wasteful for each endpoint to have its own buffer when, given the nature of USB transactions, only one such transaction can occur at a time.

Obviously this approach requires that transaction interrupts are handled sufficiently quickly that the shared buffer is freed and prepared for a new transaction in time for whatever the next transaction might be - but this is already a requirement for the control endpoint, where some SETUP transactions are immediately followed by an OUT.

So, assuming the timing is feasible, is there any other reason why such an approach wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.

Normally, the USB module on a microcontroller handles OUT packets by keeping track of which packet buffers it has written data to, and it waits for your firmware to say it is done processing the buffer before accepting more data from the computer and overwriting the buffer.  If an endpoint has no buffers available to receive more data, but the computer sends an OUT packet to the endpoint, the USB module typically responds to the computer with a NAK packet, which tells the computer it should retry later.  In this situation, your firmware can take pretty much as long as it wants to handle the OUT packets.

By having multiple endpoints configured to use the same buffer, you mess up this system.  When you receive an OUT packet on any of your endpoints, the USB module would (probably) not know that multiple endpoints use the same buffer, so it would not issue NAK packets on your other OUT endpoints.  If it receives another OUT packet right away, it would write it to the same buffer, overwriting the previous packet.  Therefore, whenever you receive a packet, your code would have to rush as fast as it can to do something like copying the data out of that buffer, disabling other OUT endpoints, or reassigning buffers.

Even if you can actually get this to work, it means that your scheme to save a little bit of memory turns the servicing of USB events into a real-time task (i.e. a task that requires responses from your code in a few microseconds).  If you want to add another real-time task to your system later, it will be very difficult, because you always have to be ready to be interrupted by your USB-handling code.

The SAMD21 has tons of memory (32 KB) so you probably don't need to worry about optimizing this part of it.

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't read enough of the USB spec to know, so I wonder whether there are host timing constraints that specify minimum intervals between packets to the same or different endpoints on a device.

Comment: Looks like, apart from the low-level inter-packet interval (as you say, a few microseconds), there appear to be no higher-level timing constraints on transactions. Which means that after *any* packet (SETUP or OUT) we need to be ready to receive the next packet ASAP. Which certainly suggests minimal interrupt processing and double/circular buffering may quickly become necessary - but this applies even for a single endpoint. But the question still remains: if I have multiple endpoints, are there technical reasons why they couldn't share a single such buffering/handling mechanism if I so decide?

Comment: I haven't worked with the SAMD21's USB module, but if it is designed well, you don't actually need interrupts because when you receive data from the PC, the USB module automatically stores it in a packet buffer if available, and if no packet buffer is available then it responds to the computer with a NAK.  The computer will try again.

The technical reason to not have multiple endpoints sharing the same buffer is that the USB module is probably not designed for that; when you receive a packet on endpoint A, it won't automatically NAK packets on all the other OUT endpoints.

Comment: Suppose you have two OUT endpoints named A and B sharing the same buffer.  (Let's ignore control endpoints for now.)  The computer sends an OUT packet to endpoint A and that packet gets stored in the buffer.  Now your code has to race as fast as it can to either reconfigure endpoint B or copy the data out of that buffer before the computer sends a packet to endpoint B and overwrites the first packet.  If the endpoints have different buffers, you can wait indefinitely before handling an OUT packet, and no data will be lost.  This is thanks to USB's NAKing mechanism.

Comment: Excellent points, and probably worth writing up as an answer in its own right!

Comment: My initial answer assumed you knew how your system would behave with separate packet buffers.  I edited it to start from the beginning.  Please click the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: Yep, obviously some important gaps in my understanding there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [David's Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58918260/12381289).  You didn't mention the speed of the device you are creating.  A low-speed would need just a few 8-byte buffers.  A full-speed, a few 64-byte buffers.  High-speed, maybe eight 64-byte buffers, depending on your use.  A super-speed device, your still only talking a few 512-byte buffers.

I would create a ring buffer for each endpoint.  This way you are not moving data around.  You are simply using a pointer that points to an entry within a memory ring.  A full-speed device with a control endpoint, an interrupt endpoint, and two bulk endpoints, each endpoint having sixteen 64-byte entries per ring, is still only a total of 4k RAM, 1/8th of the total RAM.

However, I am not familiar with the SAMD21, so please check the specification to be sure this will work.